# PHP include image file with changing filename

Tags: php

I am completely new to PHP so forgive me if this question seems very rudimentry. And thank you in advance.

I need to include a jpg that is generated from a webcam on another page. However I need to include only the latest jpg file. Unfortunately the webcam creates a unique filename for each jpg. How can I use include or another function to only include the latest image file?
(Typically the filename is something like this 2011011011231101.jpg where it stands for year_month_date_timestamp).

Answer (score 2):

Easy way is to get the **latest image** with the help of the below code

```
$path = "/path/to/my/dir"; 

$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    

$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
  // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
      $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
      $latest_filename = $entry;
    }
  }
}

// now $latest_filename contains the filename of the newest file
```

give the source of latest image to `<img>` tag

Comment: I like the usage of `filectime()`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the images are named via pattern which relates to the date, you should be able to just use:

```
$imgs = glob('C:\images\*.jpg');
rsort($imgs);
$newestImage = $imgs[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have to know a way to determine what the latest image file is called. Maybe you can make a textfile or something where every time a new image is created the webcam writes the latest filename in the text file (so the only text in the text file is the file name of the latest image file if it makes any sense). Of course you will have to have access to the script that generates the php file.

Comment: This "answered" your question?

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward, since your file names are in order.

The first thing you need is a list of files in the directory.  The readdir ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)) function is what you are looking for.  Example script that uses it:  http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/php_list_a_directory.php

Once you have that, use `substr()` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)) to chop off the file name extensions.

You're left with an array of numbers, essentially.  From here, do a `sort` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)) and specify the `SORT_NUMERIC` flag.  Grab the number on the end, stick a .jpg back on  it, and you have the last file.

**Alternate Solution:**  Read the timestamps of files to get the last one.  This would generally be a better answer, but perhaps not in your situation if you plan to edit any of the files.

Comment: I tried following your instructions but clearly I am doing something wrong. Could you provide me with a sample code?

Comment: @Gijigogo, show us what code you have tried and I will help you find out what is wrong.  Teach a man to fish, and all that...  I'm happy to help, but would rather walk you through the thinking so you can understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

addition to @ken 's post, it's probably sorting alphabetically instead of numerically. perhaps you could try:

```
$imgs = glob('C:\images\*.jpg');
rsort($imgs, SORT_NUMERIC);
$newestImage = $imgs[0];
```

Comment: still did no work. I used both print and echo to try to display them but nothing comes up. not sure why it does not work.